# Unable to add a new service with Cloudera Manager within Cloudera Quickstart VM 5.3.0

Tags: apache-spark, cloudera, cloudera-manager, cloudera-quickstart-vm

I'm using Cloudera Quickstart VM 5.3.0 (running in Virtual Box 4.3 on Windows 7) and I wanted to learn Spark (on YARN).

I started Cloudera Manager. In the sidebar I can see all the services, there is Spark but in standalone mode. So I click on "Add a new service", select "Spark". Then I have to select the set of dependencies for this service, I have no choices I must pick HDFS/YARN/zookeeper. 
Next step I have to choose a History Server and a Gateway, I run the VM in local mode so I can only choose  localhost.

I click on "Continue" and this error occures (+ 69 traces) :

> A server error as occurred. Send the following information to
>   Cloudera.
>
> Path : http://localhost:7180/cmf/clusters/1/add-service/reviewConfig
>
> Version: Cloudera Express 5.3.0 (#155 built by jenkins on
>   20141216-1458 git: e9aae1d1d1ce2982d812b22bd1c29ff7af355226)
>
> org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException:Required
>   long parameter 'serviceId' is not present at
>   AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java line 738 in
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter$ServletHandlerMethodInvoker
>   raiseMissingParameterException()

I don't know if an internet connection is needed but I precise that I can't connect to the internet with the VM. (EDIT : Even with an internet connection I get the same error)

I have no ideas how to add this service, I tried with or without gateway, many network options but it never worked. I checked the known issues; nothing...

Someone knows how I can solve this error or how I can work around ? Thanks for any help.

Comment: did you double-click? https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Cloudera-Manager-Installation/Error-while-installing-5-0-0b2/td-p/6405

Comment: I wish I did... Unfortunately this is not because of a double-click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Julien,

Before I answer your question I'd like to make some general notes about Spark in Cloudera Distribution of Hadoop 5 (CDH5):

1. Spark runs in three different formats: (1) local, (2) Spark's own stand-alone manager, and (3) other cluster resource managers like Hadoop YARN, Apache Mesos, and Amazon EC2.
2. Spark works out-of-the-box with CHD 5 for (1) and (2). You can initiate a *local*
   interactive spark session in Scala using the `spark-shell` command
   or `pyspark` for Python without passing any arguments. I find the interactive Scala and Python
   interpreters help learning to program with Resilient Distributed
   Datasets (RDDs).

I was able to recreate your error on my CDH 5.3.x distribution. I didn't mean to take credit for the bug you discovered, but [I posted to the Cloudera developer community for feedback.](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Cloudera-Manager-Installation/Adding-Full-Spark-Service-Fails-in-Cloudera-Cluster-Manager-CDH/m-p/26336)

In order to use Spark in the QuickStart pseudo-distributed environment, see if all of the Spark daemons are running using the following command (you can do this inside the Cloudera Manager (CM) UI):

```
[cloudera@quickstart simplesparkapp]$ sudo service --status-all | grep -i spark
Spark history-server is not running                        [FAILED]
Spark master is not running                                [FAILED]
Spark worker is not running                                [FAILED]
```

I've manually stopped all of the stand-alone Spark services so we can try to submit the Spark job within Yarn.

In order to run Spark inside a Yarn container on the quick start cluster, we have to do the following:

1. Set the `HADOOP_CONF_DIR` to the root of the directory containing the `yarn-site.xml` configuration file. This is typically `/etc/hadoop/conf` in CHD5. You can set this variable using the command `export HADOOP_CONF_DIR="/etc/hadoop/conf"`.
2. Submit the job using `spark-submit` and specify you are using Hadoop YARN.

> spark-submit --class CLASS_PATH --master yarn JAR_DIR ARGS
>
> Check the job status in Hue and compare to the Spark History server. Hue should show the job placed in a generic Yarn container and Spark History should not have a record of the submitted job.
>
> References used:

- Learning Spark, Chapter 7
- [Sandy Ryza's Blog Post on Spark and CDH5](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2014/04/how-to-run-a-simple-apache-spark-app-in-cdh-5/)
- [Spark Documentation for Running on Yarn](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.0/running-on-yarn.html)